# Denoting the domain of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, complex-numbers, notation

If I have a function defined as so:
$$f(z)=z^2$$
Can I limit its domain based on its argument (angle in its $re^{i\theta}$ form) like this?
$$f(re^{i\theta}) = r^2e^{2i\theta}, 0 \leq \theta < \pi$$
Is this the correct notation and does this function become bijective if defined like this?

Comment: Add $r>0$ and it seems good to me

Answer (score 2):

It is a bijection from upper half plane to (including non-negative real axis) to $\mathbb C $.

Comment: @YadatiKiran You are right. I have corrected my answer. Though  $\theta$ is arbitrary when $r=0$ the function is still well defined. Thanks for the comment.